# Maximum number of characters associated with a named element in a column data frame

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, character, unique

I have a data frame of a couple hundred rows that looks something like the following:

Df1:

| Index | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ['Puppy'] |
| 1 | ['Lizard', 'Toad', 'Kitten', 'Puppy', 'Eagle', 'BigLadybug', 'Bear'] |
| 2 | nan |
| 3 | ['Froggie', 'Mozzie'] |

And I'm trying to find the maximum number of characters associated with a single element in Df1, so I'm trying to pretty much find all of the unique values in the Values column, but because they're in lists this makes it a bit trickier because simply using unique() doesn't work.

Comment: can you make desired ouput of example? and how are tiebreakers?

Comment: yeah sure, so out of all of these the max characters would be 'BigLadybug'

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = ['pandas, question', 'need, code, of, example', None]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['word'])
df['word'] = df['word'].str.split(', ')
```

`df`

```
    word
0   [pandas, question]
1   [need, code, of, example]
2   None
```

**Code**

```
df.explode('word')[lambda x: x['word'].str.len() == x['word'].str.len().max()]
```

result:

```
    word
0   question
```

If list is in cell of dataframe, code of example is required for answer. in the future, provide code of example plz

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but when i tried out your code it returned the longest list in the data frame rather than the longest character existing in the lists in the data frame